# How to get the position of an item in a list in redis AND why there are lrem and no llocation command

Tags: list, redis, queue

I mean, lrem can remove any given element and the complexity is O(n), get the location of a list in Redis should be O(n) too
lrem and llocation(list location) are the same operations, why there is no API called llocation but has a more complex API called lrem, really don't get that, anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: If you use Redis 6.0.6 or later, you can try [LPOS](https://redis.io/commands/lpos) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @for_stack , you have the answer.
In 6.0.6 and newer editions, there is an API called LPOS, it works.